# How to get all the owners from an NFT collection?

Tags: nft, erc-721, erc-1155

How do I get a lift of all the current owners of an NFT collection and the token id owned by each one of them?

Answer (score 3):

All other answers give valid suggestions. If you are interested in how to query directly from the smart contract, you can leverage [ERC-721](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-721)'s `ownerOf` methods.

This is a sample script base on web3JS:

```
const Web3 = require('web3');
const url = 'https://fill-in-your-endpoint-url-here';
const web3 = new Web3(url);

var abi = [{ "inputs": [{ "internalType": "uint256", "name": "tokenId", "type": "uint256" }], "name": "ownerOf", "outputs": [{ "internalType": "address", "name": "", "type": "address" }], "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function" }]
var contract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, "0xBC4CA0EdA7647A8aB7C2061c2E118A18a936f13D");
var startingIndex = 0

async function getOwner(index) {
    try {
        result = await contract.methods.ownerOf(index).call()
        console.log("NFT index:" + index + "; Owner address:" + result)
        getOwner(index + 1)
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
        console.log("Likely reache the end")
    }
}

getOwner(startingIndex)
```

To use it, create an empty folder. Copy this code into an empty javascript file, for example `go.js`. Fill in the `URL` at line 2. (BTW [chainstack](https://console.chainstack.com/projects) is a great RPC provider, our developer plan gives 3 million request for **free**).

run :

```
npm init    
npm install web3
node go
```

to see the result.

Hope that helps, happy coding.

Comment: As is stated in the help documentation you shouldn't use a header, tagline nor signature. https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/behavior.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I didn't really go through this page before!

Answer (score 2):

You can get all the owners of a collection using Moralis NFT API.

Here is a tutorial step-by-step: https://docs.moralis.io/web3-data-api/evm/how-to-get-the-owners-of-an-nft-collection

And this is an example of the results you can get. Let me know if you have any questions!

```
  "result": [
    {
      "token_address": "0xa186d739ca2b3022b966194004c6b01855d59571",
      "token_id": "692",
      "owner_of": "0xd1fa414bbd0b71292e097d18a9d5ccbb04806c31",
      "block_number": "15846571",
      "block_number_minted": "15846571",
      "token_hash": "22c43a90364cd3639c565470effc46db",
      "amount": "1",
      "contract_type": "ERC721",
      "name": "NFTPass",
      "symbol": "ATTPASS",
      "token_uri": "https://metadata.atticc.xyz/692",
      "metadata": "{\"attributes\":[{\"trait_type\":\"Name\",\"value\":\"Atticc Early Adopter Pass\"},{\"trait_type\":\"Category\",\"value\":\"Early Adopter Pass\"},{\"trait_type\":\"Number of Seats\",\"value\":\"5555\",\"display_type\":\"number\"},{\"trait_type\":\"Royalty\",\"value\":\"0\",\"display_type\":\"number\"}],\"image\":\"https://media.atticc.xyz/Pass692.webp\"}",
      "last_token_uri_sync": "2022-10-28T12:30:53.470Z",
      "last_metadata_sync": "2022-10-28T12:31:12.113Z",
      "minter_address": "0xd1fa414bbd0b71292e097d18a9d5ccbb04806c31"
    },
    {
      "token_address": "0xa186d739ca2b3022b966194004c6b01855d59571",
      "token_id": "691",
      "owner_of": "0x5e899294aa47ff846ca1f1bb096692deb0636ec0",
      "block_number": "15845243",
      "block_number_minted": "15845243",
      "token_hash": "37341fba448ccb6bcd2776aef50a69d2",
      "amount": "1",
      "contract_type": "ERC721",
      "name": "NFTPass",
      "symbol": "ATTPASS",
      "token_uri": "https://metadata.atticc.xyz/691",
      "metadata": "{\"attributes\":[{\"trait_type\":\"Name\",\"value\":\"Atticc Early Adopter Pass\"},{\"trait_type\":\"Category\",\"value\":\"Early Adopter Pass\"},{\"trait_type\":\"Number of Seats\",\"value\":\"5555\",\"display_type\":\"number\"},{\"trait_type\":\"Royalty\",\"value\":\"0\",\"display_type\":\"number\"}],\"image\":\"https://media.atticc.xyz/Pass691.webp\"}",
      "last_token_uri_sync": "2022-10-28T08:04:34.923Z",
      "last_metadata_sync": "2022-10-28T08:04:49.994Z",
      "minter_address": "0x42678905eb6fb9f0f3a1334cb23b9d393b53c138"
    }
]
```

Disclosure: I work at Moralis

Answer (score 0):

That depends on which NFT standard are we talking about here. And which blockchain. But in general, if we are talking about ETH, Solana, BNB, or any of the other **big** blockchains, there are usually third party tools/servers you can use for this. Like Alchemy or Infura.

If you wouldn't like to use such a service you can query the blockchain nodes yourself.